# Adding from textbox in form 1 to database by datagridview in another form

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have two form. Form 1 contains datagridview. While Form 2 have textbox and button_click.

When I click cell in datagridview in form 1, all data will pass to Form 2. And in Form 2, when I click button_click the value in the textBox should be inserted in database.

I get this error:

> 'Dynamic SQL generation is not supported against multiple base tables.'

This is my code in Form 2 on button_click:

```
private void btnApprove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       TextBox11.Text += cmdBuilder.GetInsertCommand().CommandText;
       data.Rows[0]["status"] = "InProgress";
       sda.Update(data);
    }
```

Comment: Sounds like the DataSource is not a single table, for instance it has a JOIN?

Comment: yes. so how can i do? I'm stuck right now :(

Comment: As the error message tells you, it cant create SQL for you when multiple tables are involved.  You can load individual tables into a DataSet and create relationships between them...or do manual updates

Comment: I JOIN the two table because that two table are in different database. can i display two table in different database on my datagridview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved myself. Just change code to this

```
 sqlconn.Open();
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Update table set status = 'InProgress'", sqlconn);
 cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
 cmd.Parameters.Clear();
```